# C# Bitmap некачественная картинка

Tags: c#, bitmap, печать

Есть WinForm приложение (не WPF!!!), нужно распечатать один из его контролов.
Использовал Bitmap, но картинка получается некачественная, размытая. А отпечатанная просто ужас. Вопрос, собственно, что я сделал не так и как повысить качество картинки?

```
private void toolStripMenuItem3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
        PrintPreviewDialog ppd = new PrintPreviewDialog();
        pd.Document = printDocument1;
        printDocument1.DocumentName = "График рабочего времени";

        if (pd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ppd.Document = printDocument1;
            if (ppd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Abort)
            {
                printDocument1.PrinterSettings = pd.PrinterSettings;
                printDocument1.Print();
            }
        }
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(tableLayoutPanel2.Width, tableLayoutPanel2.Height + 25);
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
        tableLayoutPanel2.DrawToBitmap(bmp, tableLayoutPanel2.Bounds);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, tableLayoutPanel2.Location);
    }
```

PS. `Bitmap.SetResolution()` и `PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution` пробовал, не помогают

Comment: Попробуй всё белым сначала залить, чтобы не было прозрачного фона.

Comment: Посмотри [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12510811/5045688).

Comment: Может быть это из-за того, что оригинальный bitmap рассчитан на другой размер пикселей или dpi? Даже на разных мониторах может различаться этот dpi, а уж от принтерного и подавно.